# How do you get the currently executing node binary?

Tags: node.js

In a node.js application, you can use __dirpath to get the location of the current script. Can you do the same to get the location of the currently running 'node'?

This is so that I can spawn new processes in a node application that will make sure to use the exact same node binary that was used to run the parent application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
process.execPath
```

This is the absolute pathname of the executable that started the process.

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath